# Weirdly, settings not applying in Visual Studios Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm learning java currently, and I have downloaded VS code with the Red Hat java extension pack. My problem is, modifications to the settings GUI or `settings.json` do not seem to apply.

I have 2 problems:

- .class files not being hidden in the directory / explorer

[image: files not hidden]

- I want new files made to automatically be java instead of plain text.

**What I've done:**
Googled it, and made changes to settings. However, nothings changed, even after a restart.

**My settings for user:**
[image: user settings]

**My settings for workspace:**
[image: workspace settings]

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"files.exclude" : {
  **/*.class": true    // note the * ti include
}
```

Note the `*` prior to `.class` to indicate any amount of characters.  You were excluding file names like `.class` literally and not `something.class`.